# Landing page with login

Tags: loop, login

I would like to be able to force any un-registered users to the /welcome page - Currently I have set up the following:

```
if ( trim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' ) != 'welcome' && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( home_url( 'welcome' ), 301 );

exit;

}
```

This automatically re-directs visitors to the /welcome page. On the welcome page I have a login form, however the users cannot login because it re-directs them back to the welcome page after they hit the submit button. How can I set it up so where they can login through the welcome page and then be re-directed to the homepage after a successful login?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** Paste it on `functions.php` (not tested)

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_user_redirect');

function my_user_redirect(){
  if(!is_user_logged_in()){ // only redirect use not logged in
    wp_redirect( home_url( 'welcome' ), 301 );
    exit;
  }
}
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code you have successfully, but without a login on the landing page. Instead, I included a link to the wp-login.php which I've branded using WPF-Login. Could you not do this instead?